# Error when cross-compiling libosip2 with MinGW32 (Win32)

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

Sorry, I cannot speak English well.

I Did;

1. Windows7(64bit) + Qt(C++) + MinGW32
2. Compile libosip2-3.6.0 in MSYS
3. # LIBS=-lpthread ./configure --enable-mt
4. modify internal.h : append "#define HAVE_PTHREAD_WIN32" on top
5. # make && make install
6. Compile libeXosip2-3.6.0

And I make sample code refer to "sip_reg.c" of libeXosip2-3.6.0

But, Multi-Thread is not working.. ( Error : "osip_thread_create() was not declared." ) Can anyone help?

- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/libosip2-3.6.0.tar.gz
- http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/exosip/libeXosip2-3.6.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I decide to use libosip2-4.0.0 AND libeXosip2-4.0.0

I Did;

```
1. Install pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.tar.gz
$ make clean GC
- and copy to c:\develop\pthreads-w32

2. Complie libosip2-4.0.0 in MSYS with MinGW32
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/c/develop/pthreads-w32" CPPFLAGS="-I/c/develop/pthreads-w32" LIBS="-lpthreadGC2"
- modify include/osip2/internal.h : append "#define HAVE_PTHREAD_WIN32" on top
- modify src/osip2/osip_time.c : like this..

    #elif !defined(__PALMOS__) && defined(WIN32)
    ....
    static int _osip_gettimeofday_realtime (struct timeval *tp, void *tz)
    {
        return gettimeofday(tp, tz);
    }

$ make && make install

3. Complie libeXosip2-4.0.0 in MSYS with MinGW32
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/c/develop/pthreads-w32" CPPFLAGS="-I/c/develop/pthreads-w32" LIBS="-lpthreadGC2"
- modify src/eXtl_tcp.c : refer to http://www.utterspeech.com/article/random-fixes/1

     #ifdef WIN32
    -#include <Mstcpip.h>
    +/* MinGW Fix: Replacement for Mstcpip.h */
    +
    +struct tcp_keepalive {
    +    ULONG onoff;
    +    ULONG keepalivetime;
    +    ULONG keepaliveinterval;
    +};
    +
    +#define SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS    _WSAIOW(IOC_VENDOR,4)
    +
     #endif

- modify src/eXtl_tcp.c : refer to http://www.utterspeech.com/article/random-fixes/1

     #ifdef WIN32
    -#include <Mstcpip.h>
    +/* MinGW Fix:  #include <Mstcpip.h>*/
     #include <wincrypt.h>
     #endif

$ make && make install
```

- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/libosip2-4.0.0.tar.gz
- http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/exosip/libeXosip2-4.0.0.tar.gz